# Confused about CSS, iframe hidden

Tags: css

I used a CSS code to hide an iframe behind an image :

```
<style> 
iframe{
opacity: 0;
border: 0px none transparent;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 400px;
width: 500px;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
img{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 350px;
width: 401px;
}
</style>
```

I inserted Google Ads in the header, but ads are invisible, Please help!

Comment: Post your full html (preferable working example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ). But, your google ads wouldn't happen to be served in an iframe are they? >.>

Comment: Adsense served with the JS provided code
My code : http://jsfiddle.net/L7ZBk/

Comment: Checking google's js to serve ads, it seems _they_ serve the ads in an iframe. So yeah, lesson: specifiy your css selectors!

Comment: Also, you don't need opacity: 0 and the filter for that, you can just specify `visibility:hidden`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are currently applying your style to all iframes and imgs on the document.

You should use classes or ids instead, so you apply just to certain elements.

Using classes:

```
iframe.myframe{
...
}

//or simply

.myframe{

}
```

Using ids

```
#myframe {
...
}
```

and your HTML should be:

`<iframe class="myframe">` or `<iframe id="myframe">`

Ids can only be used once per document, while classes can be used on several tags. This way your CSS should only affect specific elements, and leave the rest unaltered.

Hope it helps!